# How do I install a new version on top of an old version?

Tags: grub2, system-installation, lubuntu

I have an ASUS EeePC 1000h with four OS installed.  What I want to do is replace Lubuntu 12.04 on sda1 which has reached its EOL with Lubuntu 14.04, when it is released in a few days.  I want to do a new install not an upgrade but grub is also installed on sda1.  There are plenty of How To's  but none take into consideration grub.  So, if I proceed with the new install how do I handle the grub?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Boot Ubuntu 14.04 live disk  then format `/dev/sda1` and install Ubuntu on the same partition by choosing something else option.

After the installation completed, run [boot-repair](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair).